# xcode calling an int redefining value of an int when called in another function

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

I'm having trouble with incrementing an int from one function by calling it in another function.

At the moment the bit I'm working on looks like this:

in the .h file I declare the int and timer as this:

```
int count;
NSTimer *sequenceOn;
```

in the .m file the segment of my function looks like this:

```
-(void) sequence {
count = 1;

while (count < (target)) {


    sequenceOn = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(imagePlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 }
}

-(void)imagePlayer {

 --CODE HERE FOR PLAYING ANIMATION--
    count = count + 1;
}
```

All my other code is working fine and it should play through a series of images using the count value to decide which one to play. At the moment though it only plays the first animation and wont increment to the next one.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timers will be [fired from the run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/timerConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000806-BAJFBAIH), which your code is blocking while running the loop. You probably want to have a timer regularly call your method:

```
-(void)stopTimer {
    [sequenceOn invalidate]; 
    sequenceOn = nil;
}

-(void)sequence {
    [self stopTimer];
    count = 1;
    // start a repeating timer:
    sequenceOn = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self       
                  selector:@selector(imagePlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)imagePlayer {  
    //--CODE HERE FOR PLAYING ANIMATION--
    count = count + 1;
    if (count >= target) {
        [self stopTimer];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the last argument of `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` set to *NO*, is that what you want, it will only fire once. If not you will have to give us more code to show how `imagePlayer` is being called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your `while` loop that increments `count` or decrements `target`, so either it's an infinite loop or it never executes, depending on the value of `target`.